# How to generate linux-tools packages for customized kernel?

Tags: kernel

How to generate `linux-tools` and `linux-cloud-tools` packages for customized kernel by using Ubuntu build scripts?

Tried to add  `do_tools=true` which generates

```
linux-tools-3.14.17-generic_3.14.17_amd64.deb
```

but did not generate the base package the above one needs

```
linux-tools-3.14.17_3.14.17_amd64.deb
```

So still cannot install.

Answer (score 4):

The build target you're looking for is `binary-perarch`:

```
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch skipmodule=true
```

Somewhat related links:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/KernelMaintenance

Comment: What does `skipmodule` do?

Comment: There is no rule `binary-headers`

Answer (score 2):

Simply execute

```
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

This will create **all** of the debs, including tools, cloud-tools, lowlatency kernel, etc. It doesn't take much longer, and prevents headaches.

Comment: That does work if you use Ubuntu sources. However, how to build linux-tools starting from linux vanilla git repo?