# Where to get latest .config when building kernel from Ubuntu git repository

Tags: kernel

I am trying to compile the kernel in branch `master-next` of repository `git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-yakkety.git`. The kernel has added a lot of options vs the `4.4` kernel I currently have installed, and after copying my current `.config` from `/boot`, the command `fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd kernel_image kernel_headers -j 4` is asking me a lot of questions. Where can I find Ubuntu's official updated `.config` for this kernel? It doesn't seem like they keep it in the git repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You don't need the `.config` file if you're building from the Ubuntu kernel git repo!** If you follow [the correct, modern build process](https://askubuntu.com/a/830723/463546) the .config file will be generated automatically for the different Ubuntu architectures and flavors from a set of templates located in `debian.master/config/`.

To make edits to the default config interactively, run `fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs` before building (instead of make menuconfig)

Or edit `debian.master/config/config.common.ubuntu` (or an architecture- or flavor- specific config file) and run `fakeroot debian/rules updateconfigs`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [the Ubuntu mainline PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D) as a way to obtain a starting point .config file. Figure out which kernel in there is the closest to what you are trying to compile, install it and then steal it's config file from your /boot directory. Note that it can be difficult to figure out Ubuntu's naming convention verses the mainline naming convention, but the [Ubuntu to Mainline kernel version mapping](http://people.canonical.com/~kernel/info/kernel-version-map.html) web page might be of help.

Comment: I'll add that in order to "figure out which kernel in there is the closest", one should look at the message of the commit that was most recently been tagged (or the one before that)

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky: I added a link to the kernel mapping web page, which perhaps I should have had in the first place.

Comment: The mapping page is outdated, and to use it you need to find the last version tag anyway. So might as well look in the commit message.

Comment: Could you help answer this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/533786/how-to-generate-linux-tools-packages-for-customized-kernel The answer there seems outdated, yet I shouldn't post a duplicate question. I am so fn frustrated by Canonical never updating their wikis, or maintaining an up-to-date page on how to build the kernel.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky: Oh, yes the mapping page is a little behind. I can not help with that question. I either use the default tools package, even with a different kernel, or compile the particular thing I want to use directly. By the way, I only compile mainline kernels and use [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662#718662) method.

Comment: Looks like there's no reason to search for a .config file. Check out my new answer.